# Get value from server in client

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm trying to return a single string from my server in Electron/nodejs and having some trouble.

I have a function called handleHWCompare, which has a type and value sent to it. With certain types, I need to send the value to the server which will process and return a slightly altered string to match some specific cases in my script.

The problem is, I can't figure out how to properly use the returned data in the function.

This function has multiple types of returns, because it's used for multiple purposes. Here is my function:

```
function handleHWCompare(type, server, client, doActions = true) {

    difference = leven(server, client);

    if(difference <= 2) {
        if(doActions) {
            //do some actions
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        if(doActions) {
            //do some actions
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

I've tried a few things for this.

At the top of the function, I tried this:

```
if(type == "mobo" || type == "sku") {
    https.get('https://example.com/api/check_rules.php?type=' + type + '&value='+ client, (res) => {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (result) {
            console.log('altered: ' + result);
            client = result;
        });
    });
    console.log('variable: ' + client);
}
```

And I understand this is a problem because if sync/async, but it doesn't actually set the value in time to use it, it stays as the old one for the function.

I tried putting all the existing code from the function inside the res.on part of `https.get`, but that didn't work because it broke the `return true` and `return false`.

I tried using a callback function which almost worked but I couldn't figure out how to make the existing `return true` and `return false` parts to work, so it broke my script (I don't have the code for this anymore as I've been trying things for hours).

It seems so difficult to do such a simple thing, I don't want to rewrite my entire app structure just for this. How can I send this value and retrieve an altered version in my client inside this function?

I'm aware of things like await and promises, but no matter how hard I try I can't grasp the concept on how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps.

```js
async function handleHWCompare(type, server, client, doActions = true) {
        if(type == "mobo" || type == "sku") {
          https.get('https://pccheck.r1ss.com/api/check_rules.php?type=' + type + '&value='+ client, (res) => {
                res.setEncoding('utf8');
                res.on('data', function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    return await handleHWCompareReal(type, server, result, doActions);
                });
            }).on('error', (e) => {
              console.error(e);
            });
        } else {
            return await handleHWCompareReal(type, server, client, doActions);
        }
}

function handleHWCompareReal(type, server, client, doActions = true) {
//place your code
}
```

Comment: I've just developed a workaround to do the work on the server, but it looks like this would have worked had I gotten it sooner. Thank you!

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Thank you for understanding so much!!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just need to call your function, considering it's on scope.
But I would need more info on the code structure to be sure.

```
if(type == "mobo" || type == "sku") {
  https.get('https://example.com/api/check_rules.php?type=' + type + '&value='+ client, (res) => {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (result) {
      console.log('altered: ' + result);
      handleHWCompare(type, server, result);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Couldn't this get stuck in a loop because it would continually call itself because `type` will always be equal to "mobo" or "sku" when ran from inside this function?

Comment: sorry but I could not understand how it could loop. The if statement is outside the function, I cant see how it would be related.

Comment: The statement is not outside of the function.

Comment: So the problem with this is still the return of handleHWCompare, how do I capture that return inside the https.get request and return it to it's parent function?

Comment: Sorry but you need to narrow your error. It's really hard to help you like this, without knowledge about your code structure. In your paste bin you have some functions like `unlockClient` and some variables like `difference = leven(server, client);` that I've got no idea how they work. Please clean up your code and leave only what's not working so we can help you.

Comment: That part of the code isn't even related to the problem, the function itself works fine. It's only fetching the string from the server that isn't working. leven() just gets the number of differences between strings. I'm not getting any errors, I may be doing something wrong but I've given you everything I know

Answer (score 0):

One way to go is to create a `getAlteredClient` function that returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) like this:

```
async function getAlteredClient(type, client) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        https.get('https://example.com/api/check_rules.php?type=' + type + '&value='+ client, (res) => {
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            res.on('data', result => {
               resolve(result)
            });
        });
    });
}
```

*You might want to handle possible HTTP errors later on and make use of the `reject` function*

Now you can make your `handleHWCompare` function *async* and use `getAlteredClient` using `await`

```
async function handleHWCompare(type, server, client, doActions = true) {
    if(type == "mobo" || type == "sku") {
        client = await getAlteredClient(type, client)
    }

    difference = leven(server, client);

    if(difference <= 2) {
        if(doActions) {
            //do some actions
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        if(doActions) {
            //do some actions
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Note that you might have to change how you manage your call to `handleHWCompare`, as it is an async function now, by using either `await` or `then()`.

Comment: You are missing a `);` on the return part of the getAlteredClient function. Also, I just get an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` on line `client = await getAlteredClient(type, client)`

Comment: Are you sure you added the `async` keyword before the `handleHWCompare()` function declaration?

Comment: Yes, I copied all the code directly from your answer

Comment: The code is running fine for me. What is your Node version?

Comment: I'm using node v8.11.1 and Electron v1.8.7, I'll try again

Comment: In your image there is no `async` before the `handleHWCompare` function.

Comment: Okay, after adding async (I see now that error, my bad), the variables ran through there always seem to be undefined after processing, and `console.log()` never records anything for the client variable.

Comment: I can not see the current state of your code so it is quite hard to help. Make sure your `console.log()` is right after your call to the `getAlteredClient()` function. You can also add one before the `resolve()` call in that function to make sure the result is ok.

Comment: Yes, I did both of the things you said in my initial testing but neither of them output anything, not even a blank entry to the console. But if I add a console.log to those sections not including the resulting variable, it outputs that to console fine

Comment: I just tested myself using google.com as URL and I get the response just fine in the right order. Make sure the `type` variable allows the if statement to go through. There might be different issues at play in your code that may not be tied to the asynchronous functions. You may add your current code to the question or create another one.

Comment: The function is definitely running because if I put a `console.log()` in there with any string it works unless it contains the server result

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you mean. I guess you want something like this.

```
function getResult(type, client, callback) {

    if (type == "mobo" || type == "sku") {
        https.get('https://example.com/api/check_rules.php?type=' + type + '&value='+ client, (res) => {
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            res.on('data', function (result) {
                console.log('altered: ' + result);
                callback(result);
            });
        });
        console.log('variable: ' + client);
    } else {
        callback(client);
    }

}
```

and just use

```
getResult(type, client, result => {
    console.log(result); // result is ready here
};
```